# Wrapping C in C++, just for try/catch

Tags: c++, c

So, I have a big piece of legacy software, coded in C. It's for an embedded system, so if something goes wrong, like divide by zero, null pointer dereference, etc, there's not much to do except reboot.

I was wondering if I could implement just main() as c++ and wrap it's contents in try/catch. That way, depending on the type of exception thrown, I could log some debug info just before reboot.

Hmm, since there are multiple processes I might have to wrap each one, not just main(), but I hope that you see what I mean...

Is it worthwhile to leave the existing C code (several 100 Klocs) untouched, except for wrapping it with try/catch?

Comment: Which exceptions do you plan to catch? C doesn't throw C++ exceptions. So your try/catch won't do anything about any errors occuring in C code.

Comment: Note that VC6 try/catch **incorrectly** did catch OS exceptions like access violations. You shoul not rely on this behavior. Your compiler will have a mechanism for handling OS exceptions.

Comment: Catching an access violation can hardly be considered incorrect. Since access violations lead to undefined behaviour, anything can happen, including a catch block being executed.

Comment: *If* your embedded C++ implementation throws exceptions for access violation and divide-by-zero, then you could try compiling all that C code as C++, in which case it will suddenly start throwing exceptions. You'd have to check the compiler docs, and hope that nowhere in all that C code does anyone use "new" as a variable name. Code compiled as C will not throw exceptions just because it's called from C++ - how could it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Division by zero or null pointer dereferencing don't produce exceptions (using the C++ terminology). C doesn't even have a concept of exceptions. If you are on an UNIX-like system, you might want to install signal handlers (`SIGFPE`, `SIGSEGV`, etc.).

Comment: errm, you're right an http://www.jdl.co.uk/briefings/divByZeroInCpp.html will back you up. I have previously coded signal/interrupt/hardware error handlers, but they are o/s, even h/w specific.

I suppose I asked a rather woolly question, sorry. I think I was just hoping that wrapping C code in C++ try/catch would pass on magic error handling properties. 

Maye those were bad examples, which will have to remain o/s & h/w specific, but could try/catch at least help me collect some debugging info for other errors? e.g stack trace, register dump, etc?

Comment: yes, I know that C will never throw a C++ exception. 

But if I compile C code as if it were C++ (since C is a valid subset of C++ (and a lot of programmers when told to code in C++ just switch compilers and continue to code in C :-)), then treating the C as if it were C++ (might have to rename all files to change C *.c to *.cpp; might just need to use a different compiler), *then* the generated code will be ready to throw execptions, even though I don't change the code.

That is what I am trying to achieve - but I am afraid that I am not explaining it very well ... sorry

Comment: Yes, it will be ready to throw exceptions, but it will not throw exceptions on it's own. You would have to either use a library that throws exceptions or throw exceptions manually. But if you are doing this only for rebooting the device, I don't see the benefit. Instead of `throw Something();` you could call `ERROR();`.

Answer (score 4):

Since it's an embedded application it probably runs only on one platform.

If so its probably much simpler and less intrusive to install a proper interrupt handler / kernel trap handler for the division by zero and other hard exceptions.

In most cases this can be done with just a few lines of code. Check if the OS supports such installable exception handlers. If you're working on an OS-less system you can directly hook the CPU interrupts that are called during exceptions.

Comment: "Since it's an embedded application it probably runs only on one platform."

What an odd statement!

Comment: Odd? From experience it sounds very believable. I've worked for a large telecom manufacturer which ran their 68030 CPUs with cache disabled, as it made them "more compatible" with the original 68000s they used before. The notion of "application failure = device reboot" also strongly hints at a device built for a single application. Why choose two different platforms for that single application? (Two vendors, OK, but you'd still select two ARM vendors or 2 MIPS vendors)

Comment: Running embedded software on one single platform is very common. Usually you have a design with custom peripherals that you don't find elsewhere and it's cost optimized (e.g peripherials hard-wired to GPIO-pins ect.) Changing such from one platform to another often requires a complete rewrite of at least the IO-layer.

Comment: I agree that there are embedded systems that are only designed / implemented to run on one platform. However, I don't believe that "Since it is an embedded application it probably only runs on one platform" is valid.

Comment: OP: I really gave bad examples with division by zero, null pointer deref, sorry.

let's agree that these need to be handled by signals/interrupts/whatever. And let's agree to think in the general case (multiple platforms) whether needed or not.

If I compile my C code as C++ then the compiler will generate throws as needed and I can add an outer wrapper of try/catch. Does that seem like it might be useful?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, divide by zero or null pointer dereference won't throw exceptions. Fpe exceptions are implemented in the GNU C library with signals (SIGFPE). And are part of the C99 standard, not the C++ standard.

A few hints based in my experience in embedded C and C++ development. Depending on your embedded OS:

- Unless you are absolutely sure of what you are doing, don't try/catch between threads . Only inside the same thread. Each thread usually has its own stack.
- Throwing in the middle of legacy C code and catching, is going to lead to problems, since for example when you have jumped to the catch block out of the normal program flow, allocated memory may not be reclaimed, thus you have leaks which is far more problematic than divide by zero or null pointer dereference in an embedded system.
- If you are going to use exceptions, throw them inside your C++ code with allocation of other "C" resources in constructors and deallocation in destructors.
- Catch them just above the C++ layer.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think machine code compiled from C does the same thing with regard to exceptions, as machine code compiled for C++ which "knows" about exceptions. That is, I don't think it's correct to expect to be able to catch "exceptions" from C code using C++ constructs. C doesn't throw exceptions, and there's nothing that guarantees that errors that happen when C code does something bad are caught by C++'s exception mechanism.

Comment: Agreed, C doesn't have exceptions. What I poorly explained was that I want to wrap my C code in C++, thus making into C++ code - which only uses a small subset of the language, but which then have exception handling added by teh compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Divide by zero, null pointer dereference are not C or C++ exceptions they are hardware exceptions.

On Windows you can get hardware exceptions like these wrapped in a normal C++ exception if _set_se_translator() is used.

__try/__catch may also help. Look up __try/__catch, GetExceptionCode(), _set_se_translator() on MSDN, you may find what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I think I remember researching on how to handle `SIGSEGV` ( usually generated when derefing invalid pointer, or dividing by 0 ) and the general advise I found on the net was: do nothing, let the program die.  The explanation, I think a correct one, is that by the time you get to a SIGSEGV trap, the stack of the offending thread is trashed beyond repair.

Can someone comment if this is true?

Comment: He wanted to reboot the device after receiving `SIGSEGV`, not try to repair it.

Comment: I agree - except for letting it die. On embedded systems you generally want to reboot. I was just hoping to catch as much debug info as possible before dieing/rebooting.

Answer (score 0):

Only work on msvc

```
               
__try
{

int p = 0;
p=p / 0;
}
__except (1)
{
printf("Division by 0 \n");
}
```